# JAXB. How to fill POJO class with inner classes / lists in it using JAXB pasrsing XML?

Tags: java, jaxb, marshalling

Hi im trying to marshalling some xml into java class with inner classes in it but having a problem: inner classes doesn't fill outer class - their are nulls.

```xml
    <forms>
        <form mkgu-id="0" foreign-id="ticket-department-252-2017-12-12--0">
            <data>
                //some data
            </data>
            <rates>
                <rate indicator-id="2" value-id="45">45</rate>
                <rate indicator-id="13" value-id="49">49</rate>
                <rate indicator-id="221" value-id="55">55</rate>
                <rate indicator-id="42" value-id="60">60</rate>
                <rate indicator-id="53" value-id="65">65</rate>
            </rates>
        </form>
    </forms>
```

Heres rate and rates classes:

```java
@XmlRootElement(name = "rate")
public class Rate {

    @XmlAttribute(name = "indicator-id")
    private int indicatorId;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "value")
    private int value;

    @XmlElement(name = "rate")
    private int rate;
```

rates

```java
@XmlRootElement(name = "rates")
public class Rates {
    @XmlElement
    private ArrayList<Rate> rates;
```

And when i parse i got class implementation as String like this:

Forms{forms=[Form{mkguId=0, foreignId=ticket-department-252-2017-12-12--0, data=//some data, service=Service{id=1410073997, service='null'}, procedure=0, authority=Authority{id=1411364330, authority='null'}, date='2017-12-11 18:00:00', receivedDate='2017-12-12 07:42:31', okato='53401373000'}, rates=Rates{rates=null}}]}

some fields are not filled right. What am i missing and how to fix it?

Comment: Main class: `java public class Main {
    static Forms forms = null;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String filePath="test.xml";
        File file = new File(filePath);
        try {
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Forms.class);
            Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            Forms forms1 = (Forms) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
            forms = forms1;
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(forms);
    }
}`

Comment: Because `foreign-id`is of type `int`

Comment: @RogerGustavsson thx for answer, my bad didnt see that. But now i wonder why i got null on some fields (like rates array, authority, service, user). Do u know how to fix it? toString of Forms.class after marsh `Forms{forms=[Form{mkguId=0, foreignId=ticket-department-252-2017-12-12--0, data=Data{user=User{id='ticket-department-252-2017-12-12--0', user='null'}, service=Service{id=1410073997, service='null'}, procedure=0, authority=Authority{id=1411364330, authority='null'}, date='2017-12-11 18:00:00', receivedDate='2017-12-12 07:42:31', okato='53401373000'}, rates=Rates{rates=null}}]}`

Comment: `authority` and `user` has no value in your data. You have not provided your `Rates` and `Data` classes, so I can't tell what's wrong there. And please update your question with all new information, don't post new code and data as a comment.

Comment: @RogerGustavsson about authority and user - i just dont know is my style is normal for representing this xml as pojos, or i have to refactor them somehow. like xml says that authority and user can have some data in this elements, but this one(xml above) just not having it right? where to hold such elements information? in pojo as \@XmlElement with fieldname = pojos class name or somehow else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your class `Rate` you need to annotate your field `rate` with `@XmlValue`, not `@XmlElement`. Probably the same mistake in the `Service` class. It is the same mistake in your `User` class that you presented in an earlier edit of your post.

Comment: This is exactly what i needed to do. And about rates list been null - i just changed annotation from : `@XmlElement
    private ArrayList<Rate> rates;` to `@XmlElement(name = "rate")
    private ArrayList<Rate> rates;` And this fix last problem. Ty so much for help.